# Cascade update in collection Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, cascade

I have the following Models:
[image]

Where the "Fields" property from RegisterType is an IList.

I'm using Entity Framework 5 and I would like to know if there is any way I can update my RegisterType object and cascade to automatically add, update or remove my RegisterFields in Fields property.

I tried this

```
dbContext.Entry(registerType).State = EntityState.Modified;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

but it didn't work.

I'm using an MVC Web Project so I can't save the state of the first object I read from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the State of the RegisterField entities the same way you do for the registerType.

```
dbContext.Entry(registerType).State = EntityState.Modified;

forech (var f in registerType.Fields)
{
    dbContext.Entry(f).State = ( f.Id == default(int) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified);
}
```

Otherwise they'll all default to Unmodified and will be ignored by SaveChanges()

Also you need to make sure you set the `RegisterTypeId` on each of the RegisterField entities that are added otherwise EF will choke when you attach the registerType.

Comment: I see.. I thought that EF already had an automatic way to do this for me, thank you!